# Update updatepanel from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, updatepanel

I have a defualt.aspx which contains a updatepanel. I then have a class, myTCPClient.cs, where i have a tcpclient. When it recieves a message, it does some magic and then it should update the updatepanel by doing updatepanel1.Update(). But how do i access the updatepanel?

My only soloution is to pass the updatepanel to the class. But is that the way to do it? there must be a better way?

Comment: Are you trying to do something in the background and then send a message to the UpdatePanel (sitting in a page on someone's browser) to refresh?  Because that won't explicitly work that way.  An UpdatePanel updates (or doesn't) on a request from and response to the browser.  I suspect that what you want to do is set a Timer to poll for updates and set the Timer as an AsyncPostbackTrigger on the UpdatePanel.

Comment: yes in the background runs a tcpclient. and when the client gets a meassage i want it to update the time. So it only updates when there is a new message and not every second or so.

Comment: That's not really how webpages work.  You cannot push data from your backend to the client's webbrowser.  The webbrowser has to send a request.

Comment: See my answer with some of the details of how to do this so that your UpdatePanel only updates when there is data to display, and not on every Tick of the Timer.  However you still need the Timer to poll for changes.  There's no way to force the UpdatePanel to update except during a postback (even a partial postback is fine).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Timer to poll for changes.  You can use something like this:

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = (string)Session["Text"];
        Session["Text"] = String.Empty;

        bool hasNewText = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);

        if (hasNewText)
        {
            txtOut.Text += s;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
```

Your background process would append text into Session["Text"] as it receives data.  You would disable the Timer to start with and would Enable it when you kick off the background process.

Your UpdatePanel might look something like this:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOK" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOut" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="600px" Height="299px" Font-Names="Courier New" 
                         TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`ChildrenAsTriggers="False"` is important, because it tells your updatepanel not to update everytime the Timer posts back, but only when you call UpdatePanel1.Update().

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem and does what i need. I just hoped you could access it.